# Dynamically add a list (table) to a specific cell (column) in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to have the L column in Excel populate a Drop Down List with values (now Table?) in Excel and here is my code. I have manually created a Table called Table1 with some dummy values. I can hardcode the values inside the Table so that's not an issue. I just need to run some conditions and for some specific rows, I need to add a dropdown at the L column in Excel. Any help would be appreciated. Also, is there an easy way to color specific rows in Excel?

```
Sub button_click()
Set i = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set e = Sheets("Sheet2")
arrColumnNames = i.ListObjects("Table1")

Dim d
Dim j
d = 1
j = 13

Do Until IsEmpty(i.Range("K" & j))

If i.Range("K" & j) = "Y" Then
d = d + 1
e.Rows(d).Columns("A:E").Value = i.Rows(j).Columns("A:E").Value
i.Rows(j).Columns("L") = arrColumnNames
End If
j = j + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Let me clarify, you want to add data to an existing table? ie, add a row to the table?

Comment: no I have a table (list?) which has hardcoded data. I just want to use it for specific rows in the L column of the Excel sheet.

Comment: In short what I want to do is to add drop downs for certain rows in the L column of the Excel sheet. It seems like Drop Downs in Excel used to be called Lists and now they're being called Tables for some reason which adds to more confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what you are after. This will create a Validation List and populate the list with values of you choice.

```
Dim myRng As String

myRngr = Range("A1:A10").Address

With Range("B2").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
      AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
      Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & myRngr & ""
End With
```

To amend what range to what source data you need, you just need to change this line,

```
myRngr = Range("A1:A10").Address
```

Then you could use a loop to run through the `L column` and if a criteria is met add a validation list.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I found the answer on how to color rows:           i.Rows(j).Columns("A:L").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
where 3 is the color red.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to add a drop-down list to a table.

```
Public Sub AddDropdownListColumnToTable()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim colCount As Long

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheetName")

    colCount = sht.ListObjects(1).ListColumns.Count + 1

    sht.ListObjects(1).ListColumns.Add (colCount)
    sht.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(colCount).Name = "Criteria"
    With sht.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(colCount).DataBodyRange.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="Item One, Item Two, Item Three, Item Four"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

About coloring a row Interior.ColorIndex can be used.

```
Sub colorIt()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(2)
    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End Sub
```